# No output in Swift Playground

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I am trying to put fibonacci number in an array and wanted to see the array output in playground console but for some reason I do not see any ouput. Can someone plz help in making me understand the mistake that I am cdoing in my program ?

```
import UIKit

class FibonacciSequence {

    let includesZero: Bool
    let values: [Int]

    init(maxNumber: Int, includesZero: Bool) {
        self.includesZero = includesZero
        values = [0]
        var counter: Int
        if (includesZero == true) { counter = 0 }
        else { counter = 1 }
        for counter  <= maxNumber; {
            if ( counter == 0 ) {
                values.append(0)
                counter = 1
            }
            else {
                counter = counter + counter
                values.append(counter)
            }
        }
        println(values)

    }

    println(values)
    return values
}

let fibanocciSequence = FibonacciSequence(maxNumber:123, includesZero: true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ABakerSmith has given you a good rundown of the problems in the code as-is, but you also might want to consider, instead of a class that initializes an array member variable, writing a `SequenceType` that returns fibonacci numbers:

```
struct FibonacciSequence: SequenceType {
    let maxNumber: Int
    let includesZero: Bool

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<Int> {
        var (i, j) = includesZero ? (0,1) : (1,1)
        return GeneratorOf {
            (i, j) = (j, i+j)
            return (i < self.maxNumber) ? i : nil
        }
    }
}

let seq = FibonacciSequence(maxNumber: 20, includesZero: false)

// no arrays were harmed in the generation of this for loop
for num in seq {
    println(num)
}

// if you want it in array form:
let array = Array(seq)
```

You could of course memoize the sequence if you want to improve performance on multiple generations.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your code has errors in it; if there are errors in your code Playgrounds won't run it and you won't get any output.

- On the line `for counter  <= maxNumber;` you've got a semi-colon, but also, I'm pretty sure you can't declare a `for` loop like that, unless I'm missing something? You could use a `while` loop though.
- Why are you trying to return `values` from your `init` method?
- You've declared `values` as a constant but are then trying to change it using `append`.
- Using this code and fixing the errors stated does not produce the Fibonacci sequence, instead it produces: `[0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]`

Try this code:

```
class FibonacciSequence {
    let values: [Int]

    init(maxNumber: Int, includesZero: Bool) {
        var tempValues = includesZero ? [0] : [1]
        var current = 1

        do {
            tempValues.append(current)

            let nMinus2 = tempValues[tempValues.count - 2]
            let nMinus1 = tempValues[tempValues.count - 1]

            current = nMinus2 + nMinus1

        } while current <= maxNumber

        self.values = tempValues
    }
}
```

Then create an instance:

```
let fibanocciSequence = FibonacciSequence(maxNumber:123, includesZero: true)
println(fibanocciSequence.values) // [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: No need to force-unwrap `last` – optionals can be compared to non-optionals.

Comment: Cheers, I've amended by answer.